# JRuby iterate over a collection

Tags: collections, jruby

I have a sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl object which JRuby sees as a "Collection". Since the collection is likely to contain multiple x509 certificates, I'm trying to iterate over the collection and print out all of the certs.

Can somebody provide some pointers as to how this can be achieved please.

Regards,

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
your_object.each{|each|puts each}
```

This will print each element in the collection.

Comment: Yes I tried that. It throws the following type error: TypeError: can't convert Java::SunSecurityX509::X509CertImpl into String

Comment: What about `puts each.to_s` or `puts each.toString()` then?

Comment: Same issue unfortunately! TypeError: can't convert Java::SunSecurityX509::X509CertImpl into String

Comment: Weird. Do you get the same when printing the objects with Java?

Comment: Try `your_object.each{|each|puts each.methods.sort}` and see what you've got to work with...

Answer (score 0):

In my code

```
cert_chain = key_store.getX509CertificateChain(key_alias)
```

=> Java::JavaUtil::Collections::UnmodifiableRandomAccessList

This is a collection and you can use standard Ruby methods

```
cert_chain.size
```

=> 4

```
cert_chain[0]
```

=> Java::SunSecurityX509::X509CertImpl

You can't iterate over this as a collection because it isn't one.

```
cert_chain[0].publicKey
```

=> Java::SunSecurityRsa::RSAPublicKeyImpl